# Array of undefined values

Tags: javascript

I am not able to understand if there is an array of empty values as:

```js
let arr=[,,,];
```

and I try to log the length then I get 3 instead of 4

```js
let arr=[,,,];
console.log('length',arr.length);
console.log('arr[1]',arr[1]);
```

Comment: Is your question why `length` reports three instead of four, or something else?

Comment: yeah it's about length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trailing commas are optional in array literals (in modern JS, at least). When you have

```
[<valid array list>,]
```

this is equivalent to

```
[<valid array list>]
```

So

```
[,,,]
```

is like

```
[undefined,undefined,undefined,]
```

[The specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array-initializer) calls this construction `[ ElementList , Elision(opt) ]`

where Elision is the optional trailing comma.

> If an element is elided at the end of an array, that element does not contribute to the length of the Array.